# installing mini ccnx

Tags: software-recommendation, software-center

I want to install mini ccnx from the following site:
https://github.com/chesteve/mn-ccnx/wiki/Installing

I downloaded and installed all the requirement programs and then ran:

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone git://github.com/carlosmscabral/mn-ccnx
```

They worked properly but after the next command:

```
sudo ./mn-ccnx/util/install.sh -fnv
```

I got:

```
sudo: ./mn-ccnx/util/install.sh: command not found
```

But the `install.sh` file exists in the path `/mn-ccnx/util`.

Could you please help me, what is the problem and how can it be solved?

Comment: Is the file executable? To be sure run "chmod +x mm-ccnx/util/install.sh".

Answer (score 0):

I checked that repository and noted that the install file is not executable. Thus you must first take care of that:

`chmod +x ./mn-ccnx/util/install.sh`

And then you can run the script:

`./mn-ccnx/util/install.sh`

You will be prompted for your password for the changes required to the system.